# How to resolve InvalidRequest for batch graph APIs request

Tags: angular, azure, microsoft-graph-api, httpclient

I am getting an error while combining requests in one HTTP call for Graph APIs. I had followed the official document from [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/json-batching)

this is the error I am getting,

[image]

Steps:

1. Loading all Microsoft team chats for logged-in user
2. Iterate 20 request and call batch APIs
3. Getting "InvalidRequest" error

What is the possible way to resolve this issue?

Please provide suggestions.

Comment: Hey @Kishan Vaishnani, I did reproduce this issue and the solution worked for me; do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot?

Comment: @AjayKumarGhose-MT Thanks for your time. Yes, the issues got resolved

Comment: Glad to be of help:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the workaround you may follow :
Based on the given [**`MS DOC`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/json-batching#first-json-batch-request) we have tried with microsoft graph api and tested successfully.

We have tried the given MS DOC example with below request body ;

```
{
    "requests": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "method": "GET",
            "url": "/me/drive/root:/{file}:/content"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "method": "GET",
            "url": "/me/planner/tasks"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "method": "GET",
            "url": "/groups/{id}/events"
        },
        {
            "id": "4",
            "url": "/me",
            "method": "PATCH",
            "body": {
                "city": "Redmond"
            },
            
            "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

In request header we have added the key value and run the query as below:

[image]

NOTE:- *Make sure that you have formatted correctly in your request body while making an API call.*

For more information please refer the below links:-

- [***MS DOC| Batch Size limitation***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues#batch-size-is-limited)
- [***SO THREAD|400 Bad Request with MS Graph when adding list items***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67320085/400-bad-request-with-ms-graph-when-adding-list-items) , [***List private team channel members with Microsoft Graph API***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69980532/list-private-team-channel-members-with-microsoft-graph-api-in-microsoft-teams?rq=1)

Comment: Ok let me check

Comment: I tried but still got the same error. But thank you for your time to check it

Comment: Hello @KishanVaishnani ,May i know if you are trying with MS Graph api with the same format

Comment: Yes, I will prepare some sample code and put that in original question.

Comment: Also please try to signoff & sign in again, It may help .

Comment: The provided solution worked. Thanks, Ajaykumar.